# How to use UNSUBSCRIBE command in Redis 2.6.11

Tags: redis

Published a message to a particular channel.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> PUBLISH channel message
(integer) 0
```

Using another Redis client I subscribed the channel .

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SUBSCRIBE channel
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "channel"
3) (integer) 1
```

In the Redis client I got all the Published messages. Now I want to unsubscribe from the subscribed channel. But I cant type unsubscribe in the Redis client. When I use Ctrl+c full Redis client quits. How to write the Unsubscribe command in Redis Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can issue unsubscribe in the client cause the client was blocked.
I wrote a ruby script to show how to use unsubscribe.

```
require 'redis'
r = Redis.new
r.subscribe 'first' do |on|
  on.message do |e, d|
    puts e
    puts d
    r.unsubscribe
  end
end
puts "script was blocked?"
```

If you remove r.unsubscribe, the script will be blocked.
And you can add if clause to check when to unsubscribe client.ex:

```
r.unsubscribe if d == 'leave'
```