# When block finishes executing, ruby interpreter does not continue to next instruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following execution sequence. When import gets called, it in turn invokes perform_tasks and then goes into a redis subscribe loop on on_complete:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.import(params)
    peform_tasks params[:record]
    on_complete
  end

  def self.peform_tasks(record_params)
    record_params.each do |param|
      AddressWorker.perform_async param
    end
  end

  def self.on_complete
    redis.subscribe('address_notifier') do |payload|
      on_post_execute payload
    end
    puts 'BUT WE NEVER GET HERE'
  end

  def self.on_post_execute(payload)
   puts 'Yes we get here'
  end
end
```

The problem is when the block finishes executing, and on_post_execute runs, execution does not leave the block. And we never get to the line:

```
puts 'BUT WE NEVER GET HERE'
```

Why don't we get to the line after the block?

Note that the use of `redis.subscribe` from the ruby redis gem should be irrelevant here, since I get to the block and it is a regular ruby block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `redis.subscribe` isn't exactly irrelevant here as you've noted.

This method is a [loop](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/fd77358708920b3b7b76955eda22e8c89647aae5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb#L43) that won't break until you `unsubscribe`. So, in this case I don't think you're actually exiting that block, hence your `puts` line wouldn't be executed.

```
  def self.on_complete
    redis.subscribe_with_timeout(5, 'address_notifier') do |payload|
      on_post_execute payload

      redis.unsubscribe
    end
    puts 'Should get here now'
  end

  def self.on_post_execute(payload)
    puts 'Yes we get here'
  end
```

Alternatively use `subscribe_with_timeout`:

```
  def self.on_complete
    redis.subscribe_with_timeout(5, 'address_notifier') do |payload|
      on_post_execute payload
    end
    puts 'Should get here now'
  end

  def self.on_post_execute(payload)
    puts 'Yes we get here'
  end
```

Comment: And how am I supposed to unsubscribe? How am I supposed to get out of the loop?

Comment: @Donato should just be able to call `redis.unsubscribe` from within that block after you make your call to `on_post_execute`

Comment: redis.unsubscribe was not enough! I had to use break keyword to break out of block!

Comment: @Donato `break` isn't a good idea to use because it will forcefully break the block even if it's not done doing what you need it to. There is already a conditional break clause in the `subscribe` method. That needs to stay conditional, otherwise you're overriding the functionality of the method. Yours is a basic use case so it's probably not an issue, but if you ever need more complex logic then that will cause bugs. Instead, try using `Redis#subscribe_with_timeout`, which will exit the block gracefully f no message is received after 5 seconds. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: In addition, the reason this is weird for you is because you're using the `subscribe` method in kind of an odd way. Generally speaking, there should be another block inside of `subscribe` block that handles the relevant redis messaging. My hunch is that the `unsubscribe` action has to be called from there. See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633634/how-to-use-unsubscribe-command-in-redis-2-6-11

Comment: I figured out what was going on. Redis.current.get("address_validation_key") was returning a string and I thought it was returning an integer. So the message was not being published.

Comment: The redis.unsubscribe did work. I did not have to use subscribe_with_timeout

Comment: Glad to hear. I'll update the example with both examples.